# When did the abuse of notation $y=y(x)$ start?

Tags: notation, ho.history-overview

It's quite common nowadays to name a function and the application of the function to its input with the same letter. (Possibly more so in applied areas. Certainly many calculus textbooks do this.)

When did this practice start?

In particular, did any of the old masters like Newton, Leibniz, Euler etc. ever write something like $y=y(x)$?

**Clarification:** The question is really about the history of this practice. With whom did it start? 
I didn't want to discuss merits or demerits of this notation. If you want to provide a non standard interpretation of $y=y(x)$, please also back it up with historical references.

Comment: if you understand = as the operator of assignment (rather than equality), there is not really any "abuse of notation" --- $y=y(x)$ then assigns $y$ to be a function of $x$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Well, you could also keep the traditional interpretation of =, and say that we are overloading the symbol $y$, to denote a variable on the left and a function on the right, so it is not technically abuse of notation. But that is not the argument I wanted to get into. My question is about the history of the usage.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker But I have to add, I don't understand your interpretation at all. The $y$ on which side is being assigned to what? And before you made that assignment, what was the meaning of $y$ (a variable or a function?)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636332/the-origin-of-the-function-fx-notation doesn't answer the question, but may be worth a look.

Comment: Every mathematical notation are a compromise between readability and rigor. The lack of rigor isn't a problem when what is meant is obvious, depending on the context, and Newton, Euler, etc. did understand that.

Comment: @user1952009  so are you saying Newton and Euler used this notation? If so could you provide reference?

Comment: [See there](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//docs/originals/E213.pdf) Euler writes $y = \alpha\sin (\pi x)+\beta\sin (2 \pi x)+\gamma\sin (3 \pi x)+\ldots$ using the same notation as Bernouilli

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see why that is an example of the abuse of notation I am asking for. Why should it be wrong to write that?

Comment: @user1952009 maybe you are confusing the concept of of something being a "function", with the concept of something being a "function of x". So when Euler writes $y=x^2$, the $y$ is a function of $x$, but $y$ is not a _function_ in the modern sense. On the other hand when $f=(x\mapsto x^2)$ then $f$ is a function, but it is not a function of $x$. Of course in this case $y=f(x)$.

Comment: My personal conjecture (after browsing some texts) is that we cannot find it in the "founding fathers" : Newton, Leibniz, Euler, etc. Th possible source can be the Lagrange-Cauchy notation for derivative; when $y=f(x)$, Lagrange uses indifferently $f'(x)$ as well as $y'$. Maybe, the source for the sloppy notation was the first that "commented" a cartesian diagram of speed vs time with the formula : $v=v(t)$...

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA! Do you happen to have an explicit reference to where Lagrange used $f'(x)$ and $y'$ indifferently? And concerning you last sentence: do you know any early instances of the formula $v=v(t)$ being used?

Comment: See : Joseph Louis Lagrange, [Théorie des fonctions analytiques](https://books.google.it/books?id=i2ZLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA19) (1813), page 19 : "Nous appellerons la fonction $fx$, *fonction primitive* par rapport aux fonctions $f'x, f''x,$ etc., et nou appellerons celles-ci, *fonctions dérivées* [...]. De la meme manière, si $y$ est supposée une fonction de $x$, nous dénoterons ses fonctions dérivées  par $y', y'', y''', etc.".

Comment: And see : Augustin-Louis Cauchy, [Résumé des leçons sur le calcul infinitésimal](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA9) (1823), page 9 : "Lorsque la fonction $y=f(x)$ [...] on donne à la nouvelle fonction le nom de *fonction dérivée*, et on la désigne, à l'aide d'un accent, par la notation $y'$ ou $f'(x)$."

Comment: *Comment on comments* : can be interesting to see : Joao Caramalho Domingues, [Lacroix and the Calculus](https://books.google.it/books?id=k7I2aKOqIeUC&pg=PA116) (2008), page 116, footnote 40, where the notation : "$y'$ stands for $y(x + \Delta x)$" is used in commenting the mémoire [Du calcul des dérivations, par L.F.A. Arbogast](https://books.google.it/books?id=Dz2LjO_2mN0C&pg=PR13) (1789), page xiii, where the notation is **not** used.

Comment: Thanks again @MauroALLEGRANZA. The remark by  Caramalho: "the usual 18th-century conflation between symbols for variables and for their values" is also interesting. I can not quite make sense of it and wonder if it has real substance. But I do believe that one big change in the calculus of the old days, and how it is understood now is in the treatment of variables. For example, if $x$ is simply understood as an element of the set $\mathbb{R}$, then already $\Delta x $ and $dx$ are meaningless since neither $\Delta$ nor $d$ are maps of type $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This would be more on topic at hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3025/why-was-the-question-on-the-history-of-y-yx-put-on-hold

Comment: The notation f(x) started with Euler, I learned recently, so we certainly won't find it in Newton or Leibniz...

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Is it about (1) specifically expressions like $y = y(x)$ and $f = f(x)$ and $p = p(k)$, where the *same* symbol occurs on both sides of the equality sign? Or is it about (2) any “abuse of notation” where a function is denoted by $f(x)$ when it could be denoted by $f$? I think all the other answers have interpreted your question as being more narrowly about (1), but your own answer seems to be about (2) (in which case the answer is clear: it dates back to Euler who introduced parentheses in the first place).

Comment: @shreevatsa You are right that I'm not narrowly interested in finding the first instance of $y=y(x)$ (though that would be interesting too). I'm more generally trying to understand how it got to the point where it is considered good practice to confuse an object of type $A\to B$ with an object of type $B$. Examples would be writing $y=x^2$ and later writing $y(2)=4$. Or writing $y=f(x)$ and later calling $f$ a function of $x$ etc.

Comment: No one confounds objects of type $A\to B$ with objects of type B (except beginning undergrads, I guess). We just use the same letter to denote objects of both types at the same time.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I find your claim hard to believe, when I see how Jacobi used the notation. Also, my experience is that not only undergrads but also most professional physicists and engineers (with PhDs) have difficulties understanding the difference between f and f(x). I suggest you ask some about the difference.

Comment: We are talking about mathematicians here, mostly, no? From the moment parentheses were used in that way that notation has been used to denote dependency. Since this was before the notion of function was isolated, it is not a good way to describe that such a confusion existed. The scalar y depends on x, that's what y=y(x) (and, in many contexts even more importantly, on nothing else) How does it depend on it? Nowadays we would say that through a function, because we have functions. I

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Physicist and engineers learn mathematics from mathematicians, and I have yet to find a calculus textbook (written by professional mathematicians) that does not confound a $B$ for an $A\to B$ at some point. The rest of your comment contains several historical misrepresentations: the word function was used since Leibniz and at least since Bernoulli mathematicians gave definitions of it. So how can you claim that the notion was not yet isolated?

Comment: Maybe you think that the $f$ in $f(x)$ was not yet isolated, but even that is not so clear, since Bernoulli, Euler and Lagrange had a name for $f$: it was called a function symbol. Moreover I haven't seen Euler, Lagrange, Gauss, Riemann or several others write $y=y(x)$. So they seem to have understood that $f\neq f(x)$. Finally, the notation f(x) existed since Bernoulli and Euler (actually without parenthesis) but it did not mean "f depends on x". So how do you substantiate your claim that "From the moment parentheses were used in that way, that notation has been used to denote dependency"?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252928/when-did-the-abuse-of-notation-y-yx-start#comment720736_252928) seems either tautologous or unclear:  "From the moment parentheses were used in that way that notation has been used to denote dependency."  If "that way" means "to denote dependency" then it is of course true and requires no substantiation (as having no content); otherwise, what does it mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Regarding the original question of who started *literally writing* $y=y(x)$ or something like it, which I understand Jacobi didn't do in the quoted 1840 paper: Cayley ([1859, p. 3](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1859MmRAS..27....1C/0000003.000.html)),

> where $\Omega$ is regarded as a function of $r,v,y,$ or (as this may be expressed) where $\Omega = \Omega(r, v, y)$

sounds like an early example, in that he feels the need to explain the notation.

Answer (score 12):

This seems to have started with Jacobi around 1840, when he [re](http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html)-introduced the popular notation for partial derivatives in *[De determinantibus functionalibus](https://eudml.org/doc/147138)*. He even provides a well-intentioned justification for starting this abuse of notation: he wanted a less ambiguous notation.

While reading Jacobi one should bear in mind, that during his time the $f$ in $f(x)$ was not yet officially called the function. This modern use only started after 1900 and after Frege, Dedekind, Peano and Cantor. (For more on this see [Who first considered the $f$ in $f(x)$ as an object in itself, and who decided to call it a function?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6104/3462).) Prior to 1900 what was called the function was the $f(x)$ or the $y$ in $y=f(x)$, in other words the variable quantity, and *not* the "rule" $f$. This is also how Jacobi uses the word function below. Beware hence, that what he denotes with $f$ and calls a function, is actually a variable quantity. (In modern terminology: his $f$ is an object of type $\mathbb{R}$ and not of type $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.)

What follows is my translation of the German translation [Ueber die Functionaldeterminante](https://archive.org/stream/ueberdiefunction00jacouoft), 1941 p.2 ff:

> Before I come to the actual subject matter, I will start with some
>   remarks concerning the notation of partial differentials. And since
>   this treatise will contain repeated talk about functions, which may or
>   may not depend from one another, it seems appropriate to also add some
>   elementary considerations about these.
>
> $$2. $$
>
> To distinguish the *partial* differentials from the  *ordinary ones*,
>   hence from those where all variable quantities are seen as functions
>   of a single variabel, *Euler* and others put the partial differentials
>   in between brackets. But since an accumulation of brackets becomes
>   rather annoying for reading and writing, I have preferred to use the
>   characteristic $$ d  $$ to denote ordinary differentials and the
>   characteristic $$ \partial $$ for partial differentials. Adopting this
>   convention rules out misunderstandings. So if $f$ is a function of 
>   $x$ and $y$, I will write
>   $$ df =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy. $$
>
> Whenever a function contains only a single variable, one may use the
>   characteristic $d$ or $\partial$ indifferently. 
>   [...]
>
> In order for the partial differentials, of a function which depends on
>   more than one variable, to be completely determined, it does not
>   suffice to provide the function to be differentiated and the variable
>   with respect to which to differentiate; one must moreover express
>   which quantities remain constant during the differentiation. For
>   suppose $f$ is a function of $x,x_{1},\dotsc, x_{n}$. Take $n$
>   arbitrary functions $\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \dotsc, \omega_{n}$   of
>   these variables and consider $f$ as a  function of the variables
>   $x,\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \dotsc, \omega_{n}$. Then, when
>   $x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n}$ remain constant, the
>   $\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \dotsc, \omega_{n}$  will no longer be
>   constant with changing $x$, and neither will, when
>   $\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \dotsc, \omega_{n}$  remain constant, the
>   $x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n}$ stay constant. The expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ will hence assume completely different values,
>   depending on whether these or those quantities are assumed constant
>   during differentiation.

(In modern terminology one could rephrase this as follows: the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ associated to a coordinate chart $x,x_1,\ldots,x_n$ on a manifold, does not depend on the coordinate function $x$ alone, but also on the remaining coordinate functions $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$.)

> Suppose for example we introduce for a function $f$ of the two
>   variables $x$ and $y$, an arbitrary function $u$ of $x$ and $y$,  as
>   the second independent variable instead of $y$.  Then the differential
>   that was previously denoted by
>   $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $$
>   will now be expressed as 
>   $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +
>  \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{ \partial{u}}{{\partial x}},
>  $$ so that the same signs $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ denote
>   completely different values, depending on whether $y$ or $u$ are kept
>   constant, while differentiating  $f$ with respect to $x$.
>
> I will therefore in this treatise,  whenever partial differentials are
>   needed, not only express with the statement: $f$ is a function of
>   $x, x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n}$, that $f$ depends on these variables,  hence
>   that it remains constant when these are constant, and changes, when
>   they change — that would equally be valid, if instead of
>   $x, x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n}$ any other variables $\omega, \omega_{1}, \dotsc,
>  \omega_{n}$ functions of these, were introduced as independent
>   variables — rather when I say, $f$ *is a function of the* 
>   $x, x_{1} , \dotsc, x_{n}$ *I want the following to be understood: 
>   whenever this function is partially differentiated, the
>   differentiation should occur in such a way, that of these variables
>   only one changes while the others remain constant.*
>
> Further, if the formulas are to be free of ambiguities, the notation
>   should not only indicate the variable with respect to which the
>   differentiation is occurring,  but also the whole system of
>   independent variables, the function of which is being differentiated,
>   so that one may recognise which quantities remain constant during
>   differentiation.  And this is all the more necessary, since it is
>   unavoidable that in the same calculation or even in one and the same
>   formula, there appear partial differentials that refer to different
>   systems of independent variables, for example in the above expression
>   $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot
>  \frac{\partial{u}}{{\partial x}} $$ in which $f$ is seen as a function
>   of $x$ and $u$, while $u$ is seen as a function of $x$ and $y$; this
>   expression was precisely the one $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$
>   transitions into, when $u$ is introduced as independent variable
>   instead of $y$. But if we write next to the dependent variable all the
>   independent variables to which the partial differentiation refers,
>   then this expression can be depicted by the following formula, which
>   is free of any  ambiguity:  $$ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial x} +
>  \frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial u}\cdot
>  \frac{\partial{u(x,y)}}{{\partial x}}. $$

(To stress: he is using the same notation as function application, but he doesn't want to denote function application with it, he only wants to make explicit which variables are to be kept constant.)

> Certainly this notation, as well as every other imaginable notation
>   that would allow one to completely determine any partial
>   differentiation from the symbols alone, would become very cumbersome
>   in more general investigations or more involved formulas, yes even
>   impracticable, since with higher numbers of independent variables and
>   more terms it might happen that a formula, which can be expressed in a
>   single line, takes up a whole page. Certainly one should place the
>   highest value on a notation that eliminates any ambiguity, and which
>   makes any formula understandable on its own, without oral
>   clarifications. But when it was possible without too much disadvantage,
>   and in view of the enormous and unavoidable verbosity of the notation,
>   I settled for the shorter notation of differentials, that dispenses
>   with the specification of the independent variables.

Up to this point one might argue that his notation is justified. But he starts doing it in places where I see no reason for it. For example further down he writes

> Let $f, f_1, f_2$ etc. be mutually independent functions of the variables $x, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, and let $x$ be a variable contained in $f$ [...] it follows that the $m+1$ equations
>   \begin{align}
> f(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)&=\omega\\
> f_1(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)&=\omega_1\\
> &\ldots\\
> f_m(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)&=\omega_m
> \end{align}
>   do not determine more than $m+1$ quantities.

Here these $f$ are again variables quantities of type $\mathbb{R}$ and not of type $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and there is no need to write $(x, x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ next to the $f$'s in the equations.

I haven't been able to find similar "typing errors" in Bernoulli, Euler, Lagrange, Laplace, Gauss or Cauchy. Even after Jacobi there are several people like Riemann or Peano where I can't find this. Although it is easier to find in the second half of the 19th century. For example in Hermite or Maxwell and later in Felix Kleins lectures on mechanics as well as in Sommerfeld.

But since I have only looked at 1 or 2 works of each of the above authors, this answer is by no means conclusive.

Comment: If this answer dates the notation to Jacobi in **1840,** what to make of the [quote from Cajori's *A History of Mathematical Notations*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636332/the-origin-of-the-function-fx-notation/636380#636380), which points out that Euler in **1734** used it? He wrote both “si $f\left(\dfrac{x}{a} + c\right)$ denotet functionem quamcunque ipsius $\dfrac{x}{a} + c$.” (“$f\left(\dfrac{x}{a} + c\right)$ denotes some function of $\dfrac{x}{a} + c$”) and “Est vero $f(\dfrac{x}{a} + c)$ functio quaecunque ipsarum $a$ et $x$ nullius demensionis” — (contd)

Comment: — (contd) (“Now $f(\dfrac{x}{a} + c)$” is some function of $a$ and $x$ of zero dimensions”). So the very first time (according to Cajori) that parentheses were used to denote a function argument, the notation with the parentheses was also used as referring the function itself (the so-called “abuse of notation” that the question is about). Why does this not count? (Quoting from [E045](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E045.html), original [here](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/originals/E045.pdf), translation [here](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/e045tr.pdf))

Comment: @shreevatsa Eulers bracket notation (what we nowadays call function application) is not the abuse of notation. His $f$ in the quote is of type $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so it's ok to apply it to something of type $\mathbb{R}$ and write say $f(1)$. But Jacobis $f$ is _not_ of type $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ but of type $\mathbb{R}$ and it makes no sense to write $f(1)$ or the like. It might not be immediately obvious to you that Jacobis $f$ is of type $\mathbb{R}$ since he calls it a function. That's why I added the warning above, but I understand that I might need to provide more evidence.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold Yes his $f$ is of type $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which means that for any $t$ like his $\dfrac{x}{a}+c$, his $f(t)$ is of type $\mathbb{R}$. My point is that he refers to $f(t)$ as a function, instead of referring to $f$ as a function. Is this not the same sort of abuse-of-notation you were asking about? (I see many people complain about this, and possibly jumped to the assumption that you were asking the same.) But on rereading, perhaps your question is solely about cases where (say) $y$ is of type $\mathbb{R}$, and someone writes $y(x)$ to denote that it depends on $x$.

Comment: @shreevatsa Euler is right in referring to $f(t)$ as the function, since that is the way the terminology was used before about 1900 (see the linked question in my answer and have a look at how Euler defined "function" in for example _Institutiones Calculi Differentialis_).  I would agree with your last sentence, but would love to find a historical source who explains that they'll start writing $y(x)$ to denote that $y$ depends on $x$. Have you seen one? Certainly Jacobi doesn't explain it that way in _De determinantibus_.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen this type of notation as a help in understanding quantifiers.

Example.  Here is a statement (Bertrand's Postulate):

> for every $k > 1$ there is a prime $p$ such that $k \le p < 2k$.

This may be written, to emphasize that $p$ depends on $k$, as:

> for every $k > 1$ there is a prime $p = p(k)$ such that $k \le p < 2k$.

A reader can tell that $p$ depends on $k$ in the first one as it is. But putting $p = p(k)$ in the second one emphasizes that fact.

Comment: And we inadvertently applied the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Where in this would AC be applied? For each $k$ we would just need to choose an element from a well-ordered set.

Comment: In this particular case you can avoid AC, but people do this sort of thing all the time, and in general it amounts to AC.

Answer (score 4):

**Warning**. This is an attempt at an answer out of curiosity rather than an expert answer.

Newton has the following passage in "Recomputation of surfaces of
least resistance," (1694) (see Whiteside*, pp. 470-471):

> Unde $aabb - 2aabx+aaxx+ bbxx = aay + xxy$
>
> [capiendo fluxiones]
>
> $- 2aab\dot x + 2aax\dot x+2bbx\dot x =2x\dot xy + aa\dot y+xx\dot y$

Whiteside (ibid) writes: "The dotted letters in immediate sequel are Newtonian fluxions; that is, $\dot x = \frac {dx}{dt}$ and $\dot y = \frac {dy}{dt}$ where t is some independent variable of ‘time’."

I'd like to add that I don't think that interpreted in the context (whether historical or modern), something like $x=x(t)$ (say in parametric equations) or $y=y(x)$ (say when** $y$ represents the distance from the *$x$-axis* at a certain $x$), would be an "abuse of the notation".

*The mathematical papers of Isaac Newton Volume VI 1684-1691

** I am pretty sure I have seen something like this in historical texts, but I couldn't remember where.

Comment: Thanks for you attempt to answer this, unfortunately I don't see why that quote of Newton is an example of what I'm asking for. Concerning you last paragraph, I understand that one may argue that writing y=y(x) is not technically an abuse of notation, but if you think of the y on the right as a distance, (which is not a function of type $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$) then you are abusing the notation for function application.

Comment: I cannot see how Newton could calculate $\dot x$ without thinking of $x$ as $x(t)$, though he never wrote something like $x=x(t)$. In fact, that is why I added that comment, because the separation you have made would be only possible after having the modern definition of function.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps to understand the distinction between a function and a variable (which I find very relevant for such discussions): http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1259113/1984

Comment: Newton is not so "explicit" but, due to his "dynamical intended interpretation" of the calculus, it is correct to say that the "independent variable" is *time*. See : [Treatise of the Quadrature](https://books.google.it/books?id=z-RJAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1) (1st ed 1710), page 1 : "considering that Quantities, which increase in equal
Times, and by increasing are generated, become greater or less according to the greater or less Velocity with which they increase and are generated; 1/3

Comment: ...I sought a Method of determining Quantities from the Velocities of the Motions or Increments, with which they are generated ;
and calling these Velocities of the Motions or Increments *Fluxions* [$\dot x$], and the generated Quantities *Fluents* [$x$]." 2/3

Comment: And see [page 6](https://books.google.it/books?id=z-RJAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA6) : "let $o$ be a very small Quantity, and let $oz, oy, ox$ be the *Moments*, that is the momentaneous synchronal increments of the Quantities $z, y, x$. And if the flowing Quantities are just now $z, y, x$, then after a Moment of Time, being increas'd by their Increments $oz, oy, ox$, these Quantities shall become $z+o \dot z,y + o \dot y, x + o \dot x$". 3/3

Answer (score 4):

I don't feel that $\ f=f(x)\ $ is an abuse of notation. It is rather a message. When we have an expression like $\ f\ :=\ t^2\!\cdot\! x + s,\ $ then $\ f=f(x)\ $ means that in the future when we write $\ f'\ $ then it means $t^2$ and not $\ 2\cdot t\cdot x\ $ nor simply $\ 1.$ Otherwise, the announcement $\ f=f(x)\ $ doesn't really enter the rest of the proceeding. (Am I right?)

This notation and the calculations which follow it feels to us old-fashioned in the so-called pure mathematics because this kind of mathematical analysis appears much less these days than in the past.

We can still talk about an abuse, why not, but then there are many other convenient abuses.

Comment: Have you ever seen a historical (or modern) calculus textbook explicitly state this interpretation of $y=y(x)$? I might believe that this is how many people think of it, but this interpretation definitely abuses the standard mathematical meaning of $=$ and of function application. Also, thanks to Leibniz derivative notation it seems unnecessary.

Comment: It's not just about *unnecessary* but also about *convenient*. As we all know, notation $\ f'\ $ is convenient, it's simple. People liked it for centuries. (There is still another tricky moment about the notation involving functions and derivatives).

Comment: Responding to your last comment: there is definitely a place for $f'$-notation, namely when $f$ is a function in the modern sense. In that case it would be misleading to write $df/dx$ to denote $f'$. See this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/115416/745